# How to show customized error in yup schema test function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik, yup

```
yup.object().shape({
contactEmail: yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Contact email is required')
    .test('email-availability', "Email unavailable"  , function (value) {
      aiWebsiteBuilderUtilsFn.checkEmailValidity(value).then((isValid) => {        
        if(isValid) {
          return true;
        }
      }).catch((err) => {                        
        toast.error((err as AxiosError).response?.data.message, {
          autoClose: 2000,
          pauseOnHover: true,
        });        
        return this.createError({ message: (err as AxiosError).response?.data.message, path: (err as AxiosError).response?.data.message, type: 'email-availability'});        
      });
    })
  ,
})
```

I'm getting specific error message in catch block, which I need to show to front-end as a input error message. but I'm always getting `Email unavailable`.

How can I show the custom error message?

For workaround, I'm showing error message in toast.